# Getting file information during a Karma test

Tags: karma-jasmine, angular-cli

I have a large number of files that I run through Karma and Jasmine for testing†. In the middle of the process I get an uncaught error which halts the project. This means that I cannot easily determine which file is causing the fatal error. Is there a way to print out the name of a file as it is being tested or get similar information that I can analyze?

† More specifically, I am running an Angular project using Angular CLI, which employs Karma and Jasmine.

Edit:
I have been asked for screenshots and code, but there's not much to show. When I run karma I get this response:

```
19 09 2017 00:04:18.279:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.7.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
19 09 2017 00:04:18.281:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
19 09 2017 00:04:18.285:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
19 09 2017 00:04:42.723:INFO [Chrome 61.0.3163 (Mac OS X 10.12.6)]: Connected on socket Ml1MJK4zgJuXwLyxAAAA with id 34080921
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
.....................................................Chrome 61.0.3163 (Mac OS X 10.12.6) ERROR
  Uncaught Error: No component factory found for FooComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
  at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.bundle.js:8310

Chrome 61.0.3163 (Mac OS X 10.12.6) ERROR
  Uncaught Error: No component factory found for FooComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
  at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.bundle.js:8310
Chrome 61.0.3163 (Mac OS X 10.12.6): Executed 293 of 739 (skipped 44) ERROR (10.515 secs / 1.461 secs)
```

I am running 739 unit tests and the process halts after 293. I cannot find the file causing the FooComponent error (it's something subtle and cannot be identified with a keyword search). This is why I need to know the name of the file, or the test, or the *something* that is causing the error.

Comment: can you add more information with screenshots and code?

Comment: See the edit above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a custom Karma reporter to view more details on which tests are failing etc.

**One option is [karma-spec-reporter](https://github.com/mlex/karma-spec-reporter).**

Installation and usage is simple (copied from the github README):

```
npm install karma-spec-reporter --save-dev
```

Then add 'spec' to reporters in karma.conf.js, e.g.

```
reporters: ['spec']
```

**There are also other options for Karma reporters.**

[Karma-mocha-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-mocha-reporter) is one option.

If you're after a bit of a laugh, you could also look at the [karma-nyan-reporter](https://github.com/dgarlitt/karma-nyan-reporter) for a bit of nyan-cat relief. Perhaps surprisingly, it also seems to give some useful error logging as well.